# Add running thread objects in to an arraylist

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I am creating a small tank game using java. In that game, lifepacks and coin piles are generated at a random place on the game grid time to time. They both have a **limited lifetime** and **after lifetime expires they are vanished from the field**. When they visible on the grid, any tank can acquire them before vanish. And I want to keep the list of lifepack objects and coinpile objects in an **ArrayList** in order to access them by the game AI algorithm. I hope to implement the above concept as follows using simple java knowledge.

Following is my LifePack class.CoinPile class behaves in a similar manner:

```
public class LifePack extends Thread{
    public int healthBonus;
    public int lifetime;
    public String type;
    public Point location;
    public boolean visible;

    public LifePack(int x,int y,int lifetime){
        location=new Point(x, y);
        this.lifetime=lifetime;
        this.type="health_pack";
        this.visible=true;
        this.start();

    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){

            if(this.lifetime>0){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                    if(lifetime%1000==0){
                        System.out.println("Life pack "+this.getId()+" will be disappeared in "+this.lifetime/1000+" s");
                    }
                    this.lifetime--;
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                this.visible=false;
                this.interrupt();
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Life pack visibility = "+this.visible);
    }


}
```

I want to add the newly created LifePack Objects into an arraylist as follows:

```
public ArrayList<LifePack> lifePacks;
lifePacks = new ArrayList<LifePack>();

lifePacks.add(new LifePack(x, y, lifeTime));
```

Each time a new lifepack is created I add that lifepack object into the arraylist above. Once the lifepack's lifetime expires, I want to set the '**visible**' boolean variable in the above class to '**false**' so that I can check that variable for other purposes.

But I don't get my desired output. Can I add running thread objects into an arraylist as above and keep the thread state running or Will I have to move to a different implementation? Please somebody help me to clear this out if there is a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Your architecture in general is not very good. You are creating a new Thread for each Lifepack, so if you have lets say 1000 Lifepacks you will have a 1000 Threads running. Threads come at a price (context switching, etc. pp.) and there is really no point why you should do this here. Instead, use one game logic thread (or maybe one designated thread for all lifepacks) and check each x ms if your lifepack is still alive and do some game logic. This is the usual game architecture approach.

Comment: Thank you @dirkk. Actually my java knowledge is not that much good. I will try your idea. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with dirkk that you will spin up too many threads. But to answer your question maybe you should consider using AtomicBoolean for visible.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, one Thread checks if some entry in a list is false, some other thread sets it *to false, this needs to be thread safe*.

You could do that by synchronizing the list itself during the update operation

```
  synchronized(list){
       //update the needed entry to false
  }
```

Comment: Synchronizing on the list just to update an entry looks like a huge bottleneck.

Comment: @rethab I know. Any other idea on how to live update an entry in a list?

Comment: If it's really just a flag, then an atomic variable will do the trick. But as suggested in my post, I would change the general idea of maintaining the state of objects.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, creating threads is a bad idea. In particular, once your application comes to a point at which very many lifepacks exist. Also note that starting a thread in a constructor is very bad practice. If you want to use plain threads, implementing a runnable (java.lang.Runnable) is advisable.

In general, however, I would strongly encourage you to use the Java concurrency abstractions available in the java.util.concurrent package: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html Using an ExecutorService to run callables (java.util.concurrent.Callable) allows you to vary the number of threads quite easily.

I would also question your idea of storing all the lifepacks in the same collection and assigning each of them a state (visiblity). Spontaneously, I could think of the following scenario: once the game runs for quite some time, you will end up with a large collection of lifepacks, most of which are not used anymore. Therefore, you might want to think about having different collections for the different states a lifepack can be in. This would also make throwing away object quite easy (without traversing a collection). Aussuming that those collections would be accessed by more than one thread, you'd want them to be thread-safe. For that, you'll find various types of collections in the java.util.concurrent package as well.